# iCloud upload progress objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, icloud

Is there any way to know the status of the file uploading to iCloud?
Here the code that I used to upload:

```
 FileDocument *doc = [[FileDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:des];
    doc.data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:src];
    [doc saveToURL:des forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Fail");
        }
    }];
```

I've searched for it but cannot find the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498658/tracking-upload-progress-of-icloud-files ?

Comment: I've read it but I don't know where to put the query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447105/cannot-call-nsmetadataquerydidupdatenotification ?